# Generate a barcode inside SVG Angular 5

Tags: angular, svg, angular5, barcode

As the title states I am attempting to put a barcode within a SVG but am having trouble doing so using Angular 5.

I am using [NGX-Barcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-barcode) to generate the barcodes and have created a SVG to put the barcode within. However I cannot figure out how to put the barcode in the SVG. Any ideas/suggestions are very welcome as I am all out of ideas.

NGX-Barcode Generates a barcode like so:

```
<ngx-barcode _ngcontent-c18="" bc-element-type="svg" bc-height="30" bc-width="1" class="rotate" ng-reflect-element-type="svg" ng-reflect-width="1" ng-reflect-height="30" ng-reflect-value="KB1">
  <div class="barcode">
    <svg width="88px" height="50px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 88 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="transform: translate(0,0)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="88" height="50" style="fill:#ffffff;"></rect>
      <g transform="translate(10, 10)" style="fill:#000000;">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="3" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="6" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="11" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="13" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="18" y="0" width="3" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="22" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="26" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect> 
        <rect x="28" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="33" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="36" y="0" width="3" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="41" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="44" y="0" width="3" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="48" y="0" width="4" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="53" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="55" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="60" y="0" width="3" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="64" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="66" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</ngx-barcode>
```

And generate my SVG like so (Barcode to go in place of blue rectangle):

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 675 315">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="595" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <line x1="595" y1="0" x2="675" y2="84" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <line x1="675" y1="84" x2="675" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <line x1="675" y1="300" x2="0" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <!--Labels-->
  <text x="180" y="40" style="fill:black; font-size: 24pt; font-weight:bold;">Consumables Kanban</text>
  <text x="60" y="84" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Part #</text>
  <text x="60" y="126" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Supplier Item #</text>
  <text x="60" y="168" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Description</text>
  <text x="60" y="210" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Supplier</text>
  <text x="60" y="273" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Shelf Location</text>
  <text x="435" y="273" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Bin Quantity</text>
  <!--Details-->
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="50" height="290" fill="blue"></rect>
  <text x="241" y="84" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Item_ID}}</text>
  <text x="241" y="126" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Supplier_Item_Code}}</text>
  <text x="241" y="168" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Description}}</text>
  <text x="241" y="210" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Supplier_Name}}</text>
  <text x="200" y="273" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Location_String}}</text>
  <text x="595" y="273" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Bin_Count}}</text>
</svg>
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11zh7z)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the barcode rotated by 90°?

A couple of transforms to rotate and scale the barcode are all you need.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 675 315">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="595" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <line x1="595" y1="0" x2="675" y2="84" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <line x1="675" y1="84" x2="675" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <line x1="675" y1="300" x2="0" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"></line>
  <!--Labels-->
  <text x="180" y="40" style="fill:black; font-size: 24pt; font-weight:bold;">Consumables Kanban</text>
  <text x="60" y="84" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Part #</text>
  <text x="60" y="126" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Supplier Item #</text>
  <text x="60" y="168" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Description</text>
  <text x="60" y="210" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Supplier</text>
  <text x="60" y="273" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Shelf Location</text>
  <text x="435" y="273" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt;">Bin Quantity</text>
  <!--Details-->

<g transform="rotate(90 26 29)">
  <g transform="scale(3.36 1)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="88" height="50" style="fill:#ffffff;"></rect>
      <g transform="translate(10, 10)" style="fill:#000000;">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="3" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="6" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="11" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="13" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="18" y="0" width="3" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="22" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="26" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect> 
        <rect x="28" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="33" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="36" y="0" width="3" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="41" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="44" y="0" width="3" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="48" y="0" width="4" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="53" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="55" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="60" y="0" width="3" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="64" y="0" width="1" height="30"></rect>
        <rect x="66" y="0" width="2" height="30"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
</g>


  <text x="241" y="84" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Item_ID}}</text>
  <text x="241" y="126" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Supplier_Item_Code}}</text>
  <text x="241" y="168" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Description}}</text>
  <text x="241" y="210" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Supplier_Name}}</text>
  <text x="200" y="273" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Location_String}}</text>
  <text x="595" y="273" style="fill:black; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">{{itemData.Bin_Count}}</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't think you have understood my issue. It is not that I am struggling to rotate the SVG, it is that I cannot insert the generated SVG using the `<ngx-barcode>` module into the SVG that I have created